# Qemu monitor : How to display a model specific register content?

Tags: qemu, gdbserver

Qemu monitor command `info registers` displays CPU general purpose registers along with a handful of control registers. However, which command gives us the content of a model specific register?
I found [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2017-03/msg01559.html) by googling where they exchange idea about a patch which will supply a command but it is not said if they end up implementing the feature.